# Problem with deploying angular and spring boot app

Tags: angular, spring-boot, digital-ocean

I have the angular and spring boot application. Everting work weel on local, but I want to deploy on the server and I have problems.

I installed the `tomcat`, `nginx` and `PostgreSQL` on my droplet in digital ocean. A deploy my angular app on `var/www/html` folder and I can see my UI on the HTTP. I run the jar file of my spring boot app on `localhost 8080` and I do not have an error. But my Angular not communicating with my backed. I angular I created the  `proxy.conf.json` :

```
  {
        "/api": {
            "target": "http://localhost:8080",
          "secure": false,
          "changeOrigin": true
        }
    }
```

And in my local work well but I can not understand where is problem on droplet.

Comment: That's *not* an appropriate prod setup; you can't bind two ports, and that proxy is only designed for dev.

Comment: Ok, what I have to do?

Comment: Do you have any introduction haw to solved this problem?

Comment: Deploy them on separate hosts? Have the backend serve the frontend? Use a production grade proxy? There are many solutions, depending on your goals and constraints. I'd recommend some more research.

Comment: Ok, I will explain what I want.  I have a simple frontend application that communicate with the backend. And I want to everything execute in droplet the Digital Ocean. Backed and front-end have to be separate and communication only with ports. Does it posible to do?